# Configuring ProxyPass with Apache for angular route

Tags: angularjs, angular, apache

I have the same question as this reddit post I found https://www.reddit.com/r/apache/comments/77opw9/proxypass_with_angular_route/

So I'll just quote it...

> Im trying to setup a ProxyPass to an angular dev server running on my
>   dev box. If I use
>
> ```
> ProxyPass "/ang/" "http://localhost:58173/ang/"
> ```
>
> then everything works just fine and I can access all the routes in
>   Angular but I want 'ang' replaced with 'ang-dev' like this (doesnt
>   work):
>
> ```
> ProxyPass "/ang-dev/" "http://localhost:58173/ang/"
> ```
>
> Doing it this way Agnular doesnt properly see the routes. So I want it
>   so that if I navigate to http://mydevbox.com:58173/ang-dev/#/user then
>   the angular dev server on my dev box sees it as
>   http://localhost:58173/ang/#/user

Comment: Is this question concerning angular or angularjs?

Comment: In my case I want to proxy from a AngularJs to a Angular application. So it's mainly the Angular router that gives the problem. But I guess you would have a similar problem in AngularJs